# What namespaces are required to call an SSIS Package?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created an SSISpackage in my asp.net project.To call the ssis package, i have written the following code.

dim app as new Application()

dim package as Package=app.LoadPackage("C:\Projects\MyPackage.dtsx")

dim result as DTSExeResult=package.Execute()

Response.Write(result.Tostring())

but it shows some errors.i think some namespaces are missing.What all namespaces have to be imported?
Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the namespace that you're after is:

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.aspx)

However, this namespace is found within an assembly that is usually not referenced by default, so you'll have to manually add a reference to the:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll
```

assembly, if you'er not already referencing it.

Also note that since you're attempting to execute the package from within the context of ASP.NET, you may encounter security/permissions issues.  Please see the following links for further details in this regard:

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime & ASP.NET Identity Problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/a9d3abf5-e740-4b2b-bf47-350037b32daf/)
[Calling SSIS package from web service - Security issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/db2312dc-b319-450f-84a5-a7460f5a1da9/)
[Calling SSIS packages from ASP.NET - Packages with file system tasks end abruptly](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/ff441dc3-b43b-486b-8be1-00126cf53812/)

Also see these general links in running SSIS packages programmatically:

[Loading and Running a Local Package Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136090.aspx)
[Running SSIS package programmatically](http://blogs.msdn.com/michen/archive/2007/03/22/running-ssis-package-programmatically.aspx)

That last link contains a very important caveat for attempting to execute SSIS packages specifically from within an ASP.NET context:

> ASP.NET specific: the impersonation
>   context does not get passed to
>   additional threads SSIS package
>   creates, so the data source
>   connections will not be impersonated.
>   Also, ASP.NET can be configured to
>   recycle the worker process in case it
>   consumes too much memory to improve
>   availability of ASP.NET application.
>   Since SSIS is likely to consume a lot
>   of memory if you have lots of data, it
>   can trigger this recycling and lower
>   reliability of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime